# fsockopen() [function.fsockopen] : Error through SMPP

Tags: php, smpp

I am using SMPP with PHP for sending and receiving messages. I got this error when i am 
trying to send a message. what is the cause of this and how can i send a message ? 
thanks.

```
pfsockopen() [function.pfsockopen]: unable to connect to sms.korewireless.com:2777 (A 
connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program tries to connect to remote server, but fails to do it before timeout elapsed.

There could be plenty of reasons for this: server may be not listening this port, your firewall forbids access to it and so on.

Try to connect to that server using telnet to find where problem is.

Comment: Also if you have access to something like nmap you can check the port is open, filtered or blocked.

Answer (score 0):

SMPP usually needs a bind into their server from yours. This could include whitelisting IP's, User/Pass, etc... I would contact their help desk as it sounds to be a configuration error either on your side or theirs.